# How do you rename a Verity collection in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, verity

Can't seem to rename an existing Verity collection in ColdFusion without deleting, recreating, and rebuilding the collection.  Problem is, I have some very large collections I'd rather not have to delete and rebuild from scratch.  Any one have a handy trick for this conundrum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Verity part (without considering ColdFusion), it's easy enough to detach a collection, rename it, and reattach it again:

```
rcadmin> indexdetach
Server Alias:YourDocserver
Index Alias:CollectionName
Index Type [(c)ollection,(t)ree,(p)arametric,(r)ecommendation]:c
Save changes? [y|n]:y
<<Return>> SUCCESS

rcadmin> collpurge
Collection alias:CollectionName
Admin Alias:AdminServer
Save changes? [y|n]:y
<<Return>> SUCCESS

rcadmin> adminsignal
Admin Alias:AdminServer
Type of signal (Shutdown=2,WSRefresh=3,RestartAllServers=4):4
Save changes? [y|n]:y
<<Return>> SUCCESS
```

Now you can rename the collection directory, and re-attach.  (If you are unsure of any of these values, check them with collget before you take it offline).

```
rcadmin> collset
Admin Alias:AdminServer
Collection Alias:NewCollectionName
Modify Type (Update=0, Insert=1):1
Path:
Gateway[(o)dbc|(n)otes|(e)xchange|(d)ocumentum|(f)ilesys|(w)eb|o(t)her]:
Style Alias:
Document Access (Public=0,Secure=1,Anonymous=2):
Query Parser [(s)imple|(b)oolPlus|(f)reeText|(o)ldFreeText|O(l)dSimple|O(t)her]:

Description:
Max. Search Time(msecs):
Save changes? [y|n]:y

rcadmin> indexattach
Index Alias:NewCollectionName
Index Type [(c)ollection,(t)ree,(p)arametric,(r)ecommendation]:c
Server Alias:YourDocserver
Modify Type (Update=0, Insert=1):1
Index State (offline=0,hidden=1,online=2):2
Threads (default=3):
Save changes? [y|n]:y
<<Return>> SUCCESS
```

It should now show up again in the 'hierarchyview'.

You can also use the "merge" utility to copy content from one collection to another, with a new name.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that there is an easy way to rename a Verity collection.  You can always use

```
<cfcollection action="map" ...>
```

to assign an alias to an existing collection, provided you do not need to re-use the original name.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is not possible.  Deleting and re-creating the collection with the desired name appears to be the only approach available.